# Form.io I can't get the abstract and index view from my ResourceProvider with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, formio

I'm trying to create an entire state with `FormioResourceProvider` but I can't have the custom abstract view that I create in my folder `views/resource/resource.html`, which I set as abstract template in my Resource Provider.

```
angular.module('demoApp').provider('FoodSafetyResource', function() {
return {
  $get: function() { return null; },
  templates: {
    abstract: 'views/resource/resource.html',
    view: 'views/resource/view.html',
    index: 'views/resource/index.html',
    create: 'views/resource/create.html'
  },
  controllers: {
    index: '',
    view: '',
    delete: '',
  }
};});
```

Also, I registered my Resource Provider with `FormioResourceProvider.register`

```
 // Register all of the resources.
angular.forEach(AppConfig.resources, function(resource, name) {
  FormioResourceProvider.register(name, resource.form, $injector.get(resource.resource + 'Provider'));
});
```

I can't see the abstract view for this `$state.go('foodsafetyIndex()')`

[foodsafetyIndex() state that has to be with a title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0v2k.png)

```
<div class="panel panel-headline">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>{{ currentResource.name | capitalize }}</h2>
  </div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isActive(currentResource.name + '.view')}" ><a ui-sref="{{ baseName }}.view()">View</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isActive(currentResource.name + '.edit')}"><a ui-sref="{{ baseName }}.edit()">Edit</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isActive(currentResource.name + '.delete')}" ><a ui-sref="{{ baseName }}.delete()">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get this template that I did in the index state?.

Comment: are you using ui router?

Comment: <a ui-sref="{{ baseName }}.view()">View</a> . Yes, I using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract view does not get triggered for the `index` state on the `FormioResourceProvider`. This is only created for the `view`, `edit`, and `delete` states.

Essentially, the states that get registered look like this.

- Index - The index state which contains the data grid.
- Create - The page that creates the submission
- Abstract - The wrapper page for a submission that contains the view, edit, delete pages.

  - View - The view page for the resource submission.
  - Edit - The edit page for the resource submission.
  - Delete - The delete page for the resource submission.